# How do i set cron job for my WordPress site?

Tags: wp-cron

My target is to run a file to be executed on each day whether the WordPress site runs or not.

How to execute cron file? I have got stuck in this is issue.

This is new task for me and i don't got any correct solution to my question. Please help me to find out the solution.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with WordPress. Simply setup cron job on your server to execute PHP file.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Which file are you talking about? Your question is unclear

Comment: If you want to run a cron job each day whether Wordpress runs or not, you have to setup the cron job in the server. No way to do it in Wordpress because of the need to execute the cron job whether Wordpress runs or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use one of the web cron services. If you don't have access to a web server or are on a big host that doesn't give you access to a Control Panel then these are great. Actually, I might recommend using them in place of the cron on your server anyway since their GUI makes it easier to set them up. Plus: If you end having to run lots of tasks automatically they have APIs that allow you to quickly add very specific tasks. It's pretty awesome.

https://www.easycron.com/
https://www.webcron.org/
https://www.setcronjob.com/